# wpf - Nested Grid selection

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a grid inside another grid. When I select an item from a nested grid, then I select another one from another nested grid, the previous selection remains highlighted and if I select the previous one again, it doesn't go in the get/set. Its like the selection doesn't change if the SeletedNestedItem is not in the same nested grid as the previous one. Here is my code:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView ...
     <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
             <telerik:RadGridView ..
                  SelectedNestedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}},
                                        Path=DataContext.SelectedNestedItem}"

  public Test SelectedNestedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedNestedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                if (selectedNestedItem != value)
                {
                    selectedNestedItem = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedNestedItem));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override equals on your bound class if you want this to work:

```
if (selectedNestedItem != value)
{
```

What is happening, I should think, is you haven't so it compares the two. They are the same type so they are equal. No difference... nothing to see... move along here.

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you please explain a bit? not sure what that means

Comment: Unless you override equals on your class then any two instances will be equal. You have to tell it what makes them equal. The same id or whatever.